# Why would AJAX return NaN when no numeric data is being requested?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm playing around in the console with Vanilla JS, looking at how to retrieve data from web pages, hopefully to create a web extension to automate some details of retrieving data only provided by web.

```
datastore = {hash: <a random alphanumeric string>, value: <some string>}

button.onclick = function (){
    console.log("Sending to database");
    storeData(datastore);
}
```

The data source and data destination are different URL's and the destination does not have SSL enabled yet.

```
function storeData(data){
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("PUT", "//server/lib/insert_data.php") 
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
      console.log(xhr.readyState + ", Text: " + xhr.responseText, + ", Status: " + xhr.status);
    }
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xhr.send("option=" + data.hash);
}
```

I'm checking that the server can handle the request:

```
insert_data.php:
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['option'])){
        $source_id = $_POST['option'];
    }

    echo json_encode($option);
?>
```

The console returns NaN as the responseText, and I've spent some hours researching what this means.

```
07:50:01.828 Sending to database        Scratchpad/4:41:2
07:50:06.170 2, Text:  NaN              Scratchpad/4:114:7
07:50:06.172 4, Text:  NaN              Scratchpad/4:114:7
```

I'm not sure how to check what the server side is receiving in terms of data,
so any tips on how to debug that would be helpful.

I'm not sure if I am trying to do something that cannot be done.

Comment: `+ xhr.responseText,` <-- That last comma, here, is the issue. remove the last comma and the result will be **concatenated** instead. https://jsfiddle.net/jmn6fp7e/

Comment: This may just be a typo in your example, but in your `insert_data.php` you have `echo json_encode($option)`, yet you have not defined a variable named `$option`. Perhaps you meant `echo json_encode($source_id)`

Comment: Sonofaagun. Iam blind as a bat. Thanks.

Comment: Wow. I am really off it tonight.

Comment: @KemIngram I think both points are valid above: the javascript one is just matter of **coertion**. That additional comma, here, is causing the `+ xhr.responseText` to be casted to a number (the unary operator `+` does that, here). However, the PHP side is an issue as well, though it is not why you're getting `NaN`.

Comment: Also, there's no guarantee `$source_id` will be set the way you have written the php. You should either move the `echo json_encode($source_id)` into the if statement, or define a default value for `$source_id` before the if statement. Again, not related to the `NaN` error, but something you should fix.

Comment: Right. Good point about $source_id.